# Cannot match pattern for wordpress empty paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, wordpress

For some reason wordpress randomly inserts "blank" paragraph tags on my page. I'm finding it difficult to match the tag.. It seems like it's not completly empty but some weird character I cannot see, it's not there in the source code but generated by javascript so it's very hard to figure out what it is!!

My JS file is loaded last in `<head>`.

I'm new to regex in javascript..

it looks like this in firebug (not sure if there is a small space/tab/something or not)

```
<p></p>
```

My javascript to remove it:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    var page = jQuery('body').html();
    page.replace('/\<p\>\S*\<\/p\>/', '');
    jQuery('body').html(page);
});
```

Comment: **What?!** You shouldn't run regex on html, especially in javascript which already has deserialization (converting html code to dom elements) functionality.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use regex to _parse_ HTML, which is not really something that he's trying to do with a basic text replacement. The solution posted by `ShankarSangoli` is the best one anyway, and doesn't use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery `empty` selector instead which select all elements that have no children (including text nodes). Try this.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('body').find('p:empty').remove();
});
```

Comment: Despite me posting a regex solution, this is a much better idea. Upvoting.

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed though that it seems you can't use both jQuery(window).load AND jQuery(document).ready , why is this? Is there a workaround? I don't actually need to right now but it would be good to know for the future!

Answer (score 0):

You know the exact string, so what's the matter with just matching just that?

```
page.replace('/\<p\>\<\/p\>/','');
```

Comment: Sometimes you have characters that have no visible representation or that cannot be displayed in the current environment, I tried str.replace first which failed so I assumed this..